# Is there a way to lock an iPhone that disables most on-screen touch functionality?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-lock

When commuting I travel with my iPhone in my pocket, which randomly presses the screen.  Over time as more and more functionality has moved to the lock screen, this has become very problematic.  As of iOS 16 it is to the point where I can barely listen to podcasts because the on-screen seek and scrubbing controls constantly jump around the audio.  And every once in a while it also triggers the flashlight.

Is there a way to disable most of the on-screen functionality of the lock screen to avoid this?

Comment: Is it actually waking in your pocket, or are you not sleeping it before you put it in there? If you have raise to wake enabled, always put it top-down in your pocket [which is far less irritating than disabling raise to wake].

Comment: Have mine in a fold-over case. Never triggers anything.

Comment: @Tetsujin I do not know, but based on my usage habits I suspect it's waking in my pocket.  Especially since, unless I am misunderstanding the question, touching the screen is enough to wake it.

Comment: It should not wake on touch alone - though you might have tap to wake enabled… not a setting i've ever used so I don't know how sensitive it might be - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208081 there doesn't seem a to be a separate page for tap vs raise.